# Debugging react-native application using WIFI

Tags: debugging, react-native, ip, wifi, port

```
Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: /home/sofiane/Android/Sdk//platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.1.2:5555 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

When i use port : 8081

adb tcpip 8081

adb connect 192.168.1.2:8081

I have this error :

[image]

And when i use port : 5555

adb tcpip 5555

adb connect 192.168.1.2:5555

I have this error :

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you have connected on the same network, like in my case I connected my laptop through my phone's hotspot. Of course you also need to have internet access and make sure you have successfully installed your app to your phone using react-native run android. If you have successfully installed your app you may now remove the attached USB cable.

Then on 
Windows, just open your terminal (CMD), then type `ipconfig`, and then press enter.
You will then see the list of your IP configuration.
Your private ip address is the IPv4 Address, something like `192.168.0.10`.

On your react native project, run `react-native start` to start the metro bundler.
When the metro bundler started it will say `Running Metro Bundler on port 8081` <- this is the port that you have to connect through.

On your device go to device setting then to "Debug server host & port for device", then type the computer's private IP address plus the port where metro bundler is running, for example: `192.168.0.10:8081`.

Click on save then try to reload your app again.

Comment: Adding the port to the IP fixed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

If you are connected to an Android device over wifi you must do as advised in the last suggestion on the error screen (because `adb -s ip:port reverse ...` seems not to work):

1. With your app open, shake the device until you see the developer menu.
2. Go to "Dev Settings".
3. Set "Debug server host & port for device" to your development machine's IP at port 8081.

Answer (score 5):

As stated on [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device)

devices have to be on same wifi in order to work, then go to settings through app by shaking it and in menu select "Dev Settings": Just add pc local address to "Debug server host & port for device" like so 10.0.1.1:8081.

As  well `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` may be required.

[image]

Comment: As a side note: make sure your VPN is off, as it may interfere

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do without having to connect device and installing app initially.

1. Open project in Android Studio
2. Open "Device Manager" in Android Studio
3. Click "Pair using Wi-Fi" in Device Manager Android Studio
4. On device -> Settings -> Developer Options -> Wireless debugging -> Enable wireless debugging
5. On device -> Settings -> Developer Options -> Wireless debugging -> Pair using QR code -> Scan QR code showing in android
6. Run `adb devices` from terminal or equivalent to list the device on the same network
7. run `react-native run-android deviceId=xxxxxxxx` with xxxxxx the device name of your adb device on same wifi network showing in terminal

There you will have app debuggable from wifi

Comment: if your device running Android 10 (API level 29) or lower, try this https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#wireless

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning connect your mobile to pc and run app using react-native run:android command. then run `adb shell input keyevent 82` command. It will display a popup window and select Dev Settings.And then go to debug server host &port for device. Then Enter your `wifi` host `ip` which is also connect with your PC (use this link to get `wifi` IP [get local IP of the connected wifi](https://www.whatismyip.com/what-is-my-public-ip-address/))

and get the value of Your Local IP is:*************

and after that IP address add : `8081`

if you want to live reload through the `wifi` use this `adb shell input keyevent 82`
command and select live reload option.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on Windows, I solved it by adding rule for port **8081**.

in your case, this may help you:

```
sudo ufw allow 5555/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do when I'm having troubles with the wi-fi connection because my PC at work has firewall rules that changes all the time.

1. Turn on my "mobile hotspot", to share my connection, with the mobile connected to the wi-fi.
2. Connect my notebook on the shared network from mobile.
3. Get the IP that the mobile has generated.
4. Set "Debug server host & port for device" to that IP at port 8081.

Answer (score -1):

I had faced the same issue over trying to connect android 4.4 device for debugging with react native application .

you have to disable firewall

then connect over again , it works fine

Happy coding !!